# How to make Linux kernel

Tags: linux-kernel

I navigated to the directory usr/src/linuex-headers-2.6.38-8 and type make.
I got the following error message.

```
No rule to make target `kernel/bounds.c', needed by `kernel/bounds.s'
```

How do I solve this problem? I am using ubuntu...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you run

```
make config
```

before typing make^?  Do you have permissions to create files in the directory?  Did you look on Canonical's site for [instructions on building a kernel](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Kernel/Compile)?

If you do not want to use the source code given, you can fetch the latest kernel from GitHub.  Ordinarily, there would be copies on kernel.org, but the site was compromised recently and taken down for re-installation.

^ - If you do not want to answer a thousand questions, there are alternate commands such as

```
        make menuconfig
```

Answer (score 0):

This is copied from an [answer on the Ubuntu forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1047374):

> Installing the kernel sources using apt / aptitude / synaptic / whatsoever only puts the compressed source code into /usr/src. You need to uncompress the sources:

```
$ cd /usr/src
$ sudo tar -xvjf linux-source-$YOUR_VERSION_HERE.tar.bz2
```

> Then just change into the new /usr/src/linux-source-$YOUR_VERSION_HERE directory and built your kernel like you used to

You'll often find if you paste the exact error message into Google the answer just pops right up :)

Comment: how do I download kernel source code? If I type something like apt-get install kernel-source then wouldn't it just replace the previous kernel code? Then how do I get the compressed source code?

Comment: Have a look at the link to the Ubuntu forums, other people have also had problems when the code is already uncompressed, I think the last answer on that page should sort it out

Comment: I downloaded the source code and inside of the source there is no makefile. If I type 'make' from the previous directory then I got the same error. I read the posting but it is still confusing..